# Can we access Windows 8 WinRT API from desktop application and Windows Phone 8 app? If so, are they in different namespaces?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

Over the course of time I received a number of comments on my blog in this area. Many questions were asked like “Can you use WinRT from Desktop applications?”, “Can you use WinRT from .NET applications?”, “Can you use WinRT from .NET applications?” etc? If so, how?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can and for more information refer to http://kishore1021.wordpress.com/2012/08/14/can-you-use-windows-8-winrt-api-from-net-desktop-applications/

Coming to architecting such applications, the best way to go forward is to develop a Portable Class Library and access the API's that can be used from Desktop, Store and Phone apps. By this kind of design, you don't rewrite the business logic code for each device. For detailed information on PCL, see http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/This+Week+On+Channel+9/TWC9-August-10-2012

The subset of the Win32 and COM API that can be used in a Metro style app is indicated in the header files in the Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Metro style Apps. Look for the following statements in the header files:

```
#pragma region Application Family

#pragma region Desktop Family
```

Answer (score 0):

More of that sort:

- From [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/457335/How-to-call-WinRT-APIs-from-NET-desktop-apps)
- From [Intel Developer Zone](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-winrt-apis-from-desktop-applications)